# Embed youtube video (cc_lang_pref param doesn't work in Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, embed, captions

I have embedded a video which contains english and spanish subtitles (with this order). I have set the "cc_lang_pref=es", in order for the spanish subtitles to automatically be selected upon click. But, when using Chrome, the English subtitles appear instead (in IE & Firefox works fine). Note that I am signed out of any google/gmail/chrome accounts before trying it.

The embed code:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="620" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RoaBaLyF_jw?cc_lang_pref=es&amp;cc_load_policy=1?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" wndid="RoaBaLyF_jw"></iframe>
```

Any ideas? Is this some known issue with Chrome?

Thnx!

Comment: Did you find out anything here?

Answer (score 0):

The url paramters are not valid (`&amp;`)

> Not valid: ?cc_lang_pref=es`&amp;`cc_load_policy=

> Valid: ---- ?cc_lang_pref=es`&`cc_load_policy=

```html
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="620" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RoaBaLyF_jw?cc_lang_pref=es&cc_load_policy=1?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" wndid="RoaBaLyF_jw"></iframe>
```

Thanks